# Unity/Photon PUN players don't see each other's rooms and create new ones

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

recently I have started creating a mobile game and decided to have a multiplayer feature. I watched youtube tutorials and got the basics but for some unknown reason players can't see each other.

What I want to do:

1. Connect to the server
2. Join the lobby
3. Join the room, if there's no room - create a new one
4. As soon as there're 2 players in one room start the game (2 players is the minumum number of players and the maximum as well)

What I do:

1. I build the project and get the .exe file
2. I run the .exe file in order to connect to the server and create a new room (I know that at the beginning there's no room yet)
3. I run the project in Unity
4. I connect to the server to join the room created in 2., but for some reason I cannot see the room and I am creating a new one
5. As a result I get two separate rooms with only one player in each of them instead of getting one room with two players

What I did:

- I have spent last two days reading documentation and forum but to no success.
- I have found similar problems and implemented the proposed solutions (like adding IsVisible = true or IsOpen = true whenever I create a new room) but in my case they didn't work
- I added lots of Debug logs but my knowledge of Unity and Photon is not enough to fully use their potential

Here's the code responsible for Internet connection:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PhotonLobby : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public static PhotonLobby lobby;
    public GameObject battleButton;
    public GameObject cancelButton;

    private void Awake(){
        // creates the singleton, lives within the main menu screen
        lobby = this;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // connects to master photon server
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("Player has connected to the Photon master server");
        Debug.Log("Number of players connected to the master: " + PhotonNetwork.CountOfPlayersOnMaster);
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
        Debug.Log("Joined lobby");
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
        battleButton.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void OnBattleButtonClicked()
    {
        Debug.Log("Battle button was clicked");
        battleButton.SetActive(false);
        cancelButton.SetActive(true);
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }

    public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("Tried to join a random game but failed. There must be no open games available");
        CreateRoom();
    }

    void CreateRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("Trying to create a new room");
        int randomRoomName = Random.Range(0,10000);
        RoomOptions roomOps = new RoomOptions() {IsVisible = true, IsOpen = true, MaxPlayers = (byte) MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.maxPlayers};
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom("Room" + randomRoomName, roomOps);
        Debug.Log("Created room " + randomRoomName);
    }

    
    
    public override void OnCreateRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("Tried to create a new room but failed. There must already be a room with the same name");
        CreateRoom();
    }

    public void OnCancelButtonClicked()
    {
        Debug.Log("Cancel button was clicked");
        cancelButton.SetActive(false);
        battleButton.SetActive(true);
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
}
```

And the code responsible for joining/creating rooms:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PhotonRoom : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks, IInRoomCallbacks
{
    // room info
    public static PhotonRoom room;
    private PhotonView PV;
    public bool isGameLoaded;
    public int currentScene;

    // player info
    Player[] photonPlayers;
    public int playersInRoom;
    public int myNumberInRoom;
    public int playerInGame;

    // delayed start
    private bool readyToCount;
    private bool readyToStart;
    public float startingTime;
    private float lessThanMaxPlayers;
    private float atMaxPlayers;
    private float timeToStart;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // set up singleton
        if(PhotonRoom.room == null)
        {
            PhotonRoom.room = this;
        }
        else
        {
            if(PhotonRoom.room != this)
            {
                Destroy(PhotonRoom.room.gameObject);
                PhotonRoom.room = this;
            }
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
    
    public override void OnEnable()
    {
        // subscribe to functions
        base.OnEnable();
        PhotonNetwork.AddCallbackTarget(this);
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneFinishedLoading;
    }

    public override void OnDisable()
    {
        base.OnDisable();
        PhotonNetwork.RemoveCallbackTarget(this);
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneFinishedLoading;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // set private variables
        PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        readyToCount = false;
        readyToStart = false;
        lessThanMaxPlayers = startingTime;
        atMaxPlayers = 6;
        timeToStart = startingTime;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // for delay start only, count down to start
        if(MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.delayStart)
        {
            if(playersInRoom == 1)
            {
                RestartTimer();
            }
            if(!isGameLoaded)
            {
                if(readyToStart)
                {
                    atMaxPlayers -= Time.deltaTime;
                    lessThanMaxPlayers = atMaxPlayers;
                    timeToStart = atMaxPlayers;
                }
                else if(readyToCount)
                {
                    lessThanMaxPlayers -= Time.deltaTime;
                    timeToStart = lessThanMaxPlayers;
                }
                Debug.Log("Display time to start to the players " + timeToStart);
                if(timeToStart<=0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("We have started the game!");
                    StartGame();
                }
            }
        }


    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        // sets player data when we join the room
        base.OnJoinedRoom();
        Debug.Log("We are now in a room");
        photonPlayers = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList;
        playersInRoom = photonPlayers.Length;
        myNumberInRoom = playersInRoom;
        PhotonNetwork.NickName = myNumberInRoom.ToString();

        // for delay start only
        if(MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.delayStart)
        {
            Debug.Log("Displayer players in room out of max players possible (" + playersInRoom + ":" + MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.maxPlayers + ")");
            if(playersInRoom > 1)
            {
                readyToCount = true;
            }
            if(playersInRoom == MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.maxPlayers)
            {
                readyToStart = true;
                if(!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
                    return;
                PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }

        // for non delay start
        else if (playersInRoom == 2)
        {
            Debug.Log("We have started the game!");
            StartGame();
        }

        else {
            Debug.Log("There's only 1 player");
        }
    }

    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        base.OnPlayerEnteredRoom(newPlayer);
        Debug.Log("A new player has joined the room");
        photonPlayers = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList;
        playersInRoom++;

        if(MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.delayStart)
        {
            Debug.Log("Displayer players in room out of max players possible (" + playersInRoom + ":" + MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.maxPlayers + ")");
            if(playersInRoom > 1)
            {
                readyToCount = true;
            }
            if(playersInRoom == MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.maxPlayers)
            {
                readyToStart = true;
                if(!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
                    return;
                PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void StartGame()
    {
        
            isGameLoaded = true;
            if(!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
                return;
            if(MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.delayStart)
            {
                PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.IsOpen = false;
            }
            PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.multiplayerScene);
        
      
    }

    void RestartTimer()
    {
        lessThanMaxPlayers = startingTime;
        timeToStart = startingTime;
        atMaxPlayers = 6;
        readyToCount = false;
        readyToStart = false;
    }

    void OnSceneFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        // called when multiplayer scene is loaded
        currentScene = scene.buildIndex;
        if(currentScene == MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.multiplayerScene)
        {
            isGameLoaded = true;

            // for delay start game
            if(MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.delayStart)
            {
                PV.RPC("RPC_LoadedGameScene", RpcTarget.MasterClient);
            }

            // for non delay start game
            else
            {
                RPC_CreatePlayer();
            }
        }
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void RPC_LoadedGameScene()
    {
        playersInRoom++;
        if(playerInGame == PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length)
        {
            PV.RPC("RPC_CreatePlayer", RpcTarget.All);
        }

    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void RPC_CreatePlayer()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "PhotonNetworkPlayer"),transform.position,Quaternion.identity, 0);
    }

    public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherplayer)
    {
        base.OnPlayerLeftRoom(otherplayer);
        Debug.Log(otherplayer.NickName+ "Has left the game");
        playersInRoom--;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: Add a Debug.Log at every place where you close the room and see what's happening. Unity editor should be the first client, not the build. Also add MultiplayerSetting.multiplayerSetting.maxPlayers output so that we're 100% sure it's more than 1.

Comment: Photon has their own min and max players handling, I'm not sure you're making full use of it. And you can also get the player count from the current room list, without having to double it in your with your own playersInRoom variable -- it's always risky to create redundant values as some bug may make it go off the real value. On another note, a great way to debug Photon is to create two Unity editor windows side by side, this way you get live debugging. The way I do it is to install 2 slightly different Unity version, then have them both point at the same scripts folder via Windows simlinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the solution, the problem were regions to which my players connected. I have set the region to eu and it worked. I believe that preciously each player connected to different region.
I hope it will help someone in the future

Comment: Signed in to stackoverflow just to say thankyou! was stuck for the past 5 hours on this weird thing.....

Answer (score 3):

If you connect to Photon Cloud, make sure clients are connected to the same virtual application (AppId, AppVersion) and to the same servers (Region).
If you are using the default Best Region connection method, you need to consider that clients could end up connected to two different regions.
Go through our "[Matchmaking Checklist](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/lobby-and-matchmaking/matchmaking-and-lobby#matchmaking_checklist)".